# Codeigniter pagination does not work for the second page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Codeigniter pagination does not work for me. It displays page numbers and first 5 search results, but when I click on the page '2' it loads 'search_nok' view with message "Please select your options". Could you please check my code below and help me to find the mistake. 
**Here is my controller:**

```
     public function search($offset = 0) {
            $limit = 5;

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('model_x');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country','required');

           if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $country = $this->input->post('country');

            $this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/abc/cont/search/'; //where 'http://localhost/abc' is my base url
$config['total_rows'] = 14;
$config['per_page'] = 5; 

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            if ($this->model_x->did_search($country, $limit, $offset)){

            $data["results"] = $this->model_x->did_search($country, $limit, $offset); 
            $this->load->view("search_ok",$data);           
            }          
            }
            else
            {
            $data['message'] = 'Please select your options.';   

            $this->load->view("search_nok",$data);          
             }              
       }
```

**Here is my view:**

```
   <?php

echo $this->pagination->create_links();

foreach($results as $row){                  
$country = $row['country'];                     
$city = $row['city'];
?>                      
<table>
<tr>
    <td >        
    <b><?php echo $country; ?></b>    
    </td>
    <td>    
    <b><?php echo $city; ?></b>    
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us if the below answer was useful, and if it was, accept it

Comment: you answer is useful but it works only when I remove 'if form validation is ok' statement. Perhaps I should use GET method instead of POST to bypass that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about Pagination. First of all, technically all of the pagination stuff:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/abc/cont/search/'; //where 'http://localhost/abc' is my base url
$config['total_rows'] = 14;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
```

should be in your controller,  secondly, you should actually be limiting the results in your model as well, since you haven't shown your model I will come up with an example

```
$this->db->limit ($limit $offset //these will be defined in your controller)
$data = $this->db->get('whatever_table')->whatever_result_type.
return $data
```

you should define `$limit` in your controller and pass it over your your model function as a parameter that the function accepts

the controller should also have $offset and $limit defined

```
 public function search($offset = 0) {

$limit = 5;
```

when you call your model make sure to pass these over

```
$this->model_x->did_search($country, $limit, $offset);
```

then instead of just `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

do this(still in your controller remember):

```
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

then echo pagination wherever you want it in your view

Comment: thank you very much. I have just modified my code as you described and it loads first 5 search results now, but when I click on page '2' it still loads  'search_nok' view with message "Please select your options". Could you please check updated code and help me to find the mistake.

Comment: You should be putting in your controller "$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->initialize($config);" and then in your view "echo $pagination;"

Also can you please post your model? remember your model should look something like this:
public function function_name($limit $offset)
$this->db->limit ($limit $offset //these will be defined in your controller)
$data = $this->db->get('whatever_table')->whatever_result_type.
return $data